# Code stops working after changing values?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am new to AJAX and started doing recently these online tutorials.

Link to the tutorials on youtube:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=masMZc3J03I

When I use the code from the tutorials as it is it works just fine, but when I changed the values in the array and linked my own php file it stopped working. But why? The structure of the code is exactly the same. Does anybody have an answers to this?

Here is the full code from the tutorials.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="foodstore.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="process()">
    <h3>The Chuff Bucket</h3>
    Enter the food you would like to order:
    <input type="text" id="userInput" />
    <div id="underInput" />
</body>
</html>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/xml');
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>';

echo '<response>';
    $food = $_GET['food'];
    $foodArray = array('tuna', 'bacon', 'beef', 'loaf', 'ham');
    if(in_array($food, $foodArray))
        echo 'We do have ' . $food . '!';
    elseif($food=='')
        echo 'Enter a food you idiot';
    else
        echo 'Sorry punk we dont sell no ' . $food . '!'
echo '</response>';
?>
```

JavaScript:

```
var xmlHttp = createXmlHttpRequestObject()

function createXmlHttpRequestObject(){
var xmlHttp;

if(window.ActiveXObject){
    try{
        xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }catch(e){
        xmlHttp = false;
    }
}else{
    try{
        xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }catch(e){
        xmlHttp = false;
    }
}

if(!xmlHttp)
    alert("cant create that object hoss!");
else
    return xmlHttp;
 }

 function process(){
 alert("1st checkpoint f(process) - readyState: " + xmlHttp.readyState);//
 if(xmlHttp.readyState==0 || xmlHttp.readyState==4){
    alert("2nd checkpoint f(process) - readyState: " + xmlHttp.readyState);//
    food = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("userInput").value);
    xmlHttp.open("GET", "foodstore.php?food=" + food, true);
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = handleServerResponse();
    xmlHttp.send(null);
}else{
    setTimeout('process()', 1000);
  }
 }

  function handleServerResponse(){
  alert("1st checkpoint f(handleServerResponse) - readyState: " + xmlHttp.readyState);//
        if(xmlHttp.readyState==4){
        alert("2nd checkpoint f(handleServerResponse) - readyState: " + xmlHttp.readyState);//
        if(xmlHttp.status==200){
        xmlReponse = xmlHttp.responseXML;
        xmlDocumentElement = xmlReponse.documentElement;
        message = xmlDocumentElement.firstChild.data;
        document.getElementById("underInput").innerHTML = message;
        //setTimeout('process()', 1000);
    }else{
        alert('Something went wrong!');
    }
}
}
```

Comment: And... **What code are you trying to use that doesn't work?** You said that the code from the tutorials works, and that this is the code from the tutorials, so there is currently no problem for us to help you with. Additionally, it would be helpful to know what your end goal is in changing whatever code.

Comment: try without the alert(). from experience alert can 'break' your js code. Instead you can send to the console.log(). just try <(")

Comment: Well I wanted to use the same code for my own project, so at the spots where it says "food" I wrote "books" and inside the "foodArray" I listed some titles of books and changed it to "booksArray", but otherwise the code was the same. However after these changes were made the code stopped functioning. And my question is why it stopped?